# BINDing to inlined data provided by VALUES, and braces

Tags: sparql, blazegraph, wdqs

I tried the following query on [WDQS](https://query.wikidata.org):

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?string ?StringLabel ?iri ?iriLabel 
WHERE {
  VALUES ?item { wd:Q1339 }
  BIND( STR(?item) AS ?string ).
  BIND( IRI(?string) AS ?iri ).
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

And the result has `?string` and `?iri` value. However, if I place an extra pair of braces in the query expression

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?string ?StringLabel ?iri ?iriLabel 
WHERE {
  VALUES ?item { wd:Q1339 }
  {
    BIND( STR(?item) AS ?string ).
    BIND( IRI(?string) AS ?iri ).
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  }
}
```

`?string` and `?iri` in the result are empty, looking as if `?item` is missing in the first BIND expression. Why is the result different?

Comment: *"Informally speaking, bottom-up evaluation means that subqueries and nested groups are (logically) evaluated first."* From https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPARQL's "bottom-up evaluation" is often better understood by its other label, i.e., "inside-out evaluation". That is, nesting is evaluated from the innermost to the outermost.

If you flip the nesting, you'll see [the results you expected --](https://w.wiki/7dw)

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?string ?StringLabel ?iri ?iriLabel 
WHERE 
  {
    BIND( STR(?item) AS ?string ).
    BIND( IRI(?string) AS ?iri ).
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    {
      VALUES ?item { wd:Q1339 }
    }
  }
```